# Tamper detection on configuration file

Tags: c#, configuration

I want to be able to detect when a critical configuration file has been changed.

I've used [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) to create a simple configuration file but now I cannot find an easy way to encrypt the result or add a value to it to check that it has been changed.

I want to be able to either prevent unauthorized users from changing the config file or at least know if the file has been changed.

Comment: Changed in a malicious way or by another process that would require reloading the file?

Comment: Is your custom config section part of a web.config?

Comment: I'm more concerned with "user errors" I want to make sure that only a small group of people can change the file. 
And yes the file is part of bigger configuration file but not web.config

Comment: The reason I am asking is you can use aspnet_regiis tool to encrypt your custom section, thus limiting the casual access to that section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If authorized users can change the configuration file, a high-level approach would be use an asymmetric key to sign the file.  Only authorized individuals with access to the private key would be able to generate the hash, but the application could verify the legitimacy of the hash (and thus the file itself) with only the public key.  One quick implementation follows.

This implementation requires generation of three files:

1. The configuration file you want to sign.
2. A file accessible to the application that contains the configuration file hash.
3. A private configuration file that contains the private key parameters.

Files (1) and (2) are accessed by the application.  File (3) is confidential, restricted to authorized users.

The basic mechanism is this:

1. Generate an RSA key pair, and save the public and private key information. Private key information saved into File (3), and public key information is incorporated into the application.  This step is performed only once.
2. Whenever a configuration file is changed, file (3) is used to sign the file's SHA1 hash.  The hash is saved into file (2).
3. Whenever the program loads the configuration file, it generates the configuration file hash, and uses the public key to verify the signature.  If the signatures match, it continues; if they do not match, it throws an exception.

**1. Generating the RSA key pair**

The RSA key data can be generated as XML:

```
(use System.Security.Cryptography)

var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
string publicXml = csp.ToXmlString(false);
string privateXml = csp.ToXmlString(true);
```

This produces XML data in the following format.

```
 publicXML:
 <RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>oQKZR9hHrqm1tauCFYpbFlwyRNIHeyc2HCX+5htF/oc1x8Nk8i+itTzwRlgQG1cICO6lX
         A+J9/OO2x2b9JILtk2tQow10xJdIsuiBeRwe7wJRdS8+l21F/JPY0eu/xiKQy
         ukzEWLjIxGX7UXb9e4ltIxyRUUhk5G/ia1trcxfBc=
    </Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
 </RSAKeyValue>

 privateXml:
 <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>oQKZR9hHrqm1tauCFYpbFlwyRNIHeyc2HCX+5htF/oc1x8Nk8
i+itTzwRlgQG1cICO6lXA+J9/OO2x2b9JILtk2tQow10xJdIsuiBeRwe7wJRdS8+l21F/JPY0eu/xiKQ
yukzEWLjIxGX7UXb9e4ltIxyRUUhk5G/ia1trcxfBc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
<P>zpFEWa7ave3wHL7pw7pSG0KXDPRwhCzU1Z5/fLoqSrPQzbkRqU+cwDVO/6IId3HdeXE09kVIu9/HBId
vupnY9w==</P><Q>x4pmqkmB7i8g9d3G6RSeZWYde8VOS5/OHUKgM6VrlQhgyrATpxGWAzJAe5eNO2BU
axNO8fZPe+lUSCJgY6TN4Q==</Q><DP>jaNL05ayhDLHRl6dmUiDjg+N1SMyl17KHSON1O8tmoVLchQp
CQf+ukiTP3NSDNy1eNTn9MkzAyeAphlbwf5Fpw==</DP><DQ>HhmUjw9zmBhn4m7H+JTxp94ViHwk6Wd
70hIg1GmZpuuSnkCdVlBizqyf6YTc+x323ggVmo5LQyfZXOBCpgVQQQ==</DQ><InverseQ>iO0CKRGB
2ULS6is/SwonqJw5fBsI9HTzx8rmKGA189dwlLGJSJuQo8uWmrLYhuo22BAqd0lMqxlKCHv6leeGPw==
</InverseQ><D>RSLliJkRJqnO0cRkZjVzqWVLXIvHFJWgwXN7QXlik8mhSTbYqLnVpvcUwU/dErBLTf
KTZLVza9nUdLgBGIKBrkbIqIWixq1fQ3zsEkyB/FQxwhIerTrhHyPzR+i3+5mduqQ7EBTj64u6STUf0y
TXHW2FYlfAinNz+K3iQFFarEE=</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

The private key strings should be saved (through any mechanism) to File (3) (private key).  The application that is confirming the file's integrity will need the public key string (discussed later in step 3).

**2. Signing the configuration file**

To sign the configuration file, you will need the Private key Xml string generated in step (1).

```
    private byte[] GetFileSha1Hash(string file)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(
            file, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(fs);
        }
    }

    static string GetConfigurationFileSignature(string configfile, string privateXml)
    {
        var p = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        p.FromXmlString(privateXml);
        byte[] signature = p.SignHash(GetFileSha1Hash(configfile),
               CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature)
    }
```

Calling `GetConfigurationFileSignature` will return a base64-encoded string.  Save this string into File (2), where it will be referenced by the application.

**3. Check the configuration file integrity**

When the configuration file is loaded, the application should check the configuration file signature against the digital signature.  *The public key should be stored within the application rather than in a configuration file* -- otherwise, the attacker can simply overwrite the public key in the configuration file with one for which he/she knows the corresponding private key pair.

```
    static bool VerifyConfigurationFileSignature(string fileName, string publicXml, string signature)
    {
        var p = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        p.FromXmlString(publicXml);

        return p.VerifyHash(
             GetFileSha1Hash(fileName),
             CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"),
             Convert.FromBase64String(signature));
    }
```

(Note: you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` to get the path of the current configuration file.)

When the application loads, it can make a call to `VerifyConfigurationFileSignature` with the path to the configuration file, public key XML data, and known signature.  If this method returns false, it indicates the file has been tampered with; if it returns true, it is evidence that the file is legitimate.

**Final Notes**

1. The cryptography only ensures that the generated digital signature was generated with the private key.  An attacker may still be able to override the application's verification logic to read malicious configuration data.
2. Any change to the configuration file (including adding comments, whitespace, etc.) will result in the hash becoming invalid.  A more specialized implementation of `GetFileSha1Hash` might search for specific key/value pairs in the XML and sign only that data, allowing other modifications to the configuration file.
3. Including the hash itself in the XML file is not possible with the above implementation of `GetFileSha1Hash`, since updating the hash itself in the file would render the prior hash invalid.  A specialized implementation of `GetFileSha1Hash` can ignore the generated hash value in generating the configuration file hash, thus preventing the need for separate configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to determining whether something has changes is to take a 'hash', for example, you could take an [MD5 hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) of the configuration, or part of it, then check against this has each time it is loaded in order to determine if it has been changed.

Comment: Thant's my intention but I want an example - please